# how to handle the ie.refresh() pop up

Tags: c#, watin

i am trying to handle the retry button when triggering  ie.refresh().  this is what i have so far

```
                    ConfirmDialogHandler confirm = new ConfirmDialogHandler();
                    using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, confirm))
                    {
                        ie.Refresh();
                        confirm.WaitUntilExists();
                        confirm.OKButton.Click();
                        ie.WaitForComplete();
                    }
```

but it does't work as expected.  thanks

Answer (score 5):

after more digging i found RefreshWarningDialogHandler, this should do it;...thanks though

yep it it works, heres the solution i used.  i hope it helps someone who may have also had this issue.

```
                    bool retryhandler = true;
                    RefreshWarningDialogHandler refresh = new RefreshWarningDialogHandler(retryhandler);
                   using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher,refresh))
                   {
                       ie.Refresh();
                   }
                    ie.WaitForComplete();
```